# Saving XML files to clientbin

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, save, clientbin

Greetings,

I'm trying to read and save to a XML file within a client bin

I've managed to find out how to read a xml file in the clientbin.

Now I want to save to it aswell, when saving, the file already exists in the clientbin.

```
Uri url = new Uri("myXml.xml", UriKind.Relative);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
#region DownloadStringCompleted
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ea) =>
{
   //bla
}
```

If this is not possible due to limitation then please provide me with a way to copy the file to local machine and be able to change it there.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do is achievable by using an `HttpHandler` in server-side, and by creating a `HttpWebRequest` in client-side that sends to the handler all the bytes contained in the XML.

There is a good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL4FileUploadAnd_SL4_MVVM.aspx) on *CodeProject* on how to implement a FileUploader in MVVM. Try to look at the ending part.

Anyway this is not the only solution, if you prefer you can create a WCF Service that do the same job.